# How to turn array of arraybuffers into either a float32array or a normal array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, floating-point, arraybuffer

I have an array of arraybuffers, meaning that I have

```
array[1] -> once this is clicked on, in the console, it holds this 

[object ArrayBuffer][object ArrayBuffer][object ArrayBuffer][object ArrayBuffer][object ArrayBuffer][object ArrayBuffer][object ArrayBuffer][object ArrayBuffer][object ArrayBuffer][object ArrayBuffer][object ArrayBuffer][object ArrayBuffer][object ArrayBuffer]
```

I have to take these arraybuffers and turn them back into arrays that I can read from. Originally, I had only one of these and was using

```
    temp_float_array = new Float32Array(arr_buff); //turns array buffer data from hex bytes to an array of floats
    for (var i = 0; i < temp_float_array.length; i++) {
        float_array[i] = parseFloat(temp_float_array[i]);
    }
```

to take the arraybuffer and turn it into a float32array, and then from there using parseFloat to make it a normal array. Now that I have a lot of these arraybuffers I need to turn each one to a human readable array. Thanks for any help or advice.

Each arraybuffer holds about 50K values in it,

```
[-91.51844787597656,-91.5179443359375,-91.5174560546875,-91.51744842529297,-91.55493927001953,-91.5665283203125,-91.57928466796875,-91.59294128417969,-91.607177734375,-91.62168884277344...etc]
```

ideally I need these values back just as they are.

Comment: To round trip FP to text to the same FP needs at least 9 significant digits in text for float32.  To round trip text to FP to the same text, do not have more than 6 significant in text.  If text-fp-text needs more than 6 significant  digits, use float64, good for 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody in the future this is what I ended up doing.

```
    temp_float_array = new Float32Array(arr_buff); //turns array buffer data from hex bytes to an array of floats
            for (var j = 0; j < temp_float_array.length; j++) {
                part_arr[j] = parseFloat(temp_float_array[j]);
            }
            float_array = float_array + part_arr;
```

I used a nested for loop. This was inside of my main for loop, arr_buff was each individual arraybuffer. This gave me an array of float32 arrays for each arraybuffer. Outside of my main for loop I then had

```
float_array = float_array.split(',');
for (var u = 0; u < float_array.length; u++) {
    float_array[u] = parseFloat(float_array[u]);
}
```

Splitting the values at the commas and then taking float_array, which now has my array of float32 arrays and then turned that into one massive array with a few million values. Not the cleanest or fastest solution I'm sure, but my working solution for now.